# Using global string in PHP inside function more than once

Tags: php, global-variables, concatenation, global

So I have a class that looks something like this...

```
class foo{
    private $url = ""

    function createURL($contryCode){
        global $url;
        $url = 'google'
        echo $url;
        if($url == ''){exit()}
        $fullURL = "http://" . $url . $countryCode . "/";
        return $fullURL;
     }
}
```

In the next script I calling it like....

```
$address = $foo -> createURL(".us");
```

It will output the global as "google" and pass the check against null but when I concatenate it fills the string with null values.  Aside from "global is bad" I can't find a reason for this.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  A little more info...
The $address is filled with "http:///" (the http:// and / constants, but not the global).

Comment: The code certainly is working as expected, though it is somewhat cluttered. Question is why you apparently do not see what you expect. You'd have to add more information for us to be of help...

Comment: Oh, could it be that you run into a syntax error which you don't realize since you do not monitor your http servers error log file? Note that `$foo -> createURL(".us");` _is_ indeed a syntax error, it has to be `$foo->createURL(".us");` instead, and `$foo` has to be a valid object of type `foo` (there is a difference between class and object!)...

Answer (score 1):

The method implementation itself looks fine, as mentioned above in my comment. However I have the impression that you did not yet fully understand how to use that class definition of yours. Take a look at this simply example:

```
<?php
class foo{
    private $url = ""

    function createURL($contryCode){
        global $url;
        $url = 'google'
        echo $url;
        if($url == ''){exit()}
        $fullURL = "http://" . $url . $countryCode . "/";
        return $fullURL;
     }
}

$fooObj = new foo;
$address = $fooObj->createURL(".us");
var_dump($address);
```

A side note: global variables are indeed considered bad style in *most* situations. However that does not mean that they would not work as expected in general. There are two main issues with global variables and you certainly should avoid them: 1. it is very hard to debug and maintain software using such global variables and 2. they often cause collisions with other code used like libraries and pear classes using the same global variable names, which leads to unexpected behavior.

Comment: This is a more full version of the code, I am calling a function of an instance of the class.  But the $address is still returning nothing but the constants like the global vars were not even there.

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear from your question, I had to assume things.

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments: take a look into your http servers error log file, probably you will find some warning in there. You _cannot_ program in php without monitoring that log file.

Comment: The only thing I see in the php error logs in the curl failing to connect and ISS seems perfectly happy.  I have no idea whats going on.  Also sorry about the muddy state of the question.